# JQuery Get page html on load and button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this script loading a page every 3 seconds, I'd like to change it so the script runs apon page load and then a button can also run the script to pull the details again.

```
    <?php echo "<script>
      function refresh_div() {
          jQuery.ajax({
              url:'example.com/urlpage',
              type:'POST',
              success:function(results) {
                  jQuery('.queue').html(results);
              }
          });
      }

      t = setInterval(refresh_div,3000);
    </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: Use of $(document).ready() may work. [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Remove `t = setInterval(refresh_div,3000);` so the script won't run periodically

2.Wrap code in $(document).ready() so it runs once DOM load

3.Add click event for the button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function refresh_div() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:'example.com/urlpage',
      type:'POST',
      success:function(results) {
        jQuery('.queue').html(results);
      }
    });
  }
  refresh_div();
  // onclick handler for button, assuming its class is 'refresh'
  $(".refresh").click(refresh_div);
}
```